# Is there a way to clearly define a random number as a variable to use it in a function?

Tags: python, random

I cant clearly use a random int as a variable to use it for a comparison in my code. It seems to only throw out the first if statement no matter the random number produced.

```
from random import randint
rate = randint(0, 255)
wind = rate
print(rate)
if wind > 251:
    print("The hurricane is a category 5!")
elif wind <= 251 or wind >= 209:
    print("The hurricane is a category 4!")
elif wind <= 208 or wind >= 178:
    print("The hurricane is a category 3!")
```

The code is suppose to use the random number in a range to determine a rating of hurricane and print the message regarding. code works to certain extent..
no error message just always prints category 4 line no matter the random number the script produces

Comment: replace your `or`s with `and`s

Answer (score 0):

rate have a value between 0 & 255 `rate = randint(0, 255)`

wind is equal to rate `wind = rate`

First conditions check if wind is greater than 251, which will **never** be true as its a random within 0 to 250 `if wind > 251:`

Second conditions check if wind is less than 251, which will **always** be true as its a random within 0`elif wind <= 251`

**Probable Fix** : Maybe you intended to use `and` in conditions instead of `or`

Comment: Another suggestion is to write it like this: `if 178 <= wind <= 208` to prevent such errors in the future.

Comment: thanks for the tips @Umair Mohammed. I altered the code slightly to assign the randint as an int. it worked a treat.    from random import randint
    wind = randint(0, 255)
    calc_category = wind
    print(wind)